# How to upgrade a program id on Anchor

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

Everytime I deploy an Anchor program on Solana, it creates a new Program ID. Is there any way to upgrade the Anchor program using the same Program ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the anchor deploy command will deploy a new Program ID. If you want to upgrade your existing program, use this command

```
anchor upgrade target/deploy/<PROGRAM_NAME>.so --provider.cluster <CLUSTER> --program-id <PROGRAM_ID>
```

Where

- PROGRAM_NAME is the file or name of your generated .so file
- ClUSTER is which environment you'd like to deploy to (e.g "Devnet")
- PROGRAM_ID is the existing program id you'd like to upgrade to

https://project-serum.github.io/anchor/cli/commands.html#upgrade